# filter out results with a boolean property or by Id in a Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class called Level which has an Id (Int32) and a property called IsActive (bool)

In my linq query, I want to filter out a certain Level with an Id of 14672.  This Level also has the IsActive property set to "False".

I know that using the IsActive property would filter out all Levels that are inactive...which is fine.

Performance wise, and logically, would it be better to filter the results with "IsActive" or just use "!=" like below:

```
        var gameObjectives = region.Characters
            .Select(e => e.Character)
            .Where(e => e.Level.IsActive && e.Level.Equipment == Equipment.ARQ);
```

or

```
        var gameObjectives = region.Characters
            .Select(e => e.Character)
            .Where(e => e.Level.Id != 14672 && e.Level.Equipment == Equipment.ARQ);
```

Comment: They're both pretty much functionally identical. Linq will force a loop each time, so you're talking apples and oranges. One is a comparison to a bool, and one is a comparison of inequality with an ID. Pretty much the same CPU resources.

Comment: If you are running with x86 option an integer is 16 bits so it would be better with the bool.  Otherwise, it probably doesn't make any difference.

Comment: If your intent/requirement is "to filter out a certain Level with an Id of 14672", then I think using e.Level.Id != 14672 clarifies the intent better. Using IsActive may give the same result now, but later when some other Level is inactivated, then your result may be incorrect.